# Getting Autotest to work with Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, autotest

I'm trying to setup autotest to work with cucumber but despite following the tutorials it always finishes with:

```
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

I see from this blog post that I need to add something: http://monket.net/blog/2009/06/simple-example-of-autotest-cucumber-and-growl/

```
AUTOFEATURE=true
```

I wasn't sure where to add that so I tried the config/environment.rb file, and also the /config/environments/development.rb and test.rb file but it made no difference.

Anyone know how I can get autotest to run the cucumber tests? Right now I have no rspec tests, I'm starting with just cucumber.

Thanks

Comment: Also, the growl msg shows "XXXX: Could not run tests'

Comment: I also tried running 'AUTOFEATURE=true autotest' but that made no difference.

Comment: Correction, if I run 'AUTOFEATURE=true autospec' it does seem to work. First it shows that it could not run test via growl, then a few moments later it seems to run the cucumber tests. Is that normal?

Comment: Also tried adding the following to my test.rb env file: ENV['AUTOFEATURE'] = 'true'
ENV['RSPEC'] = 'true'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add AUTOFEATURE=true to autotest command when you fire the latter up. That'll run your specs first and cucumber tests second.

Be careful, though, as running cucumber as part of the autotest stuff will slow down the runtime considerably, especially if the browser it fires up is firefox.

Comment: But I always want cucumber to be tested as that's all I'm using right now?

Comment: From the horse's mouth (https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/Autotest-Integration):

If you always want to have the plugin run then you can export the variable in your .bash_profile or other shell file like so:
POSIX shell:
    $ export AUTOFEATURE=true